# Touchpad is not detected

Tags: elementary-os, touchpad, toshiba

My touchpad doesn’t get detected. I can use my touchpad as a simple mouse, but without any extra features like scrolling.

My notebook is a **Toshiba Tecra Z40-A-11R**. I'm running Elementary OS Freya (based on Ubuntu 14.04). My kernel version is **3.16.0-41-generic**.

### xinput list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - FHD                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

### lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0b97:7772 O2 Micro, Inc. OZ776 CCID Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 138a:0010 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1199:9063 Sierra Wireless, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

### lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

**What can I do so that the touchpad is detected correctly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the kernel to at least 3.17 to solve the Toshiba touchpad problem.

The package `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid` provides a 3.19 kernel, so installing this should solve your problem.

In case it's not part of the Elementary OS repository, you can find it at http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-generic-lts-vivid.